# Require 'barby' not working. - cannot load such file -- barby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, barcode, require

I'm trying to use the `barby` `gem` that I installed, but when I do it gives me this error.

```
LoadError cannot load such file -- barby
```

Here's the require methods in my controller.

```
    require 'barby'
    require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'
    require 'barby/outputter/ascii_outputter'
    require 'barby/outputter/html_outputter'

    class PalletsController < ApplicationController
    -snip-
    end
```

Here's the gem in my gemfile.

```
gem 'barby'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Omar Lahlou is right. You can remove the require lines. Have you run "bundle install" after adding the gem to your gem file. If you run "bundle" you should see "barby" listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only add `require` when you are dealing with a `ruby` project. In your case(`ruby-on-rails`), you can remove those lines.

Also, keep in mind that you should add your `gem`s into your `Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

bundle install? It sounds like you do not have the gem installed when ruby tries to load it, it can not find it. Gem list will list out the installed gems on the system, or bundle exec gem list.

```
gem list
```